# yql link list to html

Tags: html, yql

I'm using yql to return a list of links from specific webpages. So far so good, it returns all the links that I pretend, however I don't know how to translate that info into my webpage.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- YQL returns a list of links in the
  results
- I want those links to appear in my
  webpage, inside a table, inside divs,
  etc... like if i wrote them there.

I have been trying to find a way to do this but I don't know much of js and json so I'm here trying to achieve some answer from those of you that might know a way.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with YQL, nor do I fully understand your problem, but sounds like if you learn jquery - it will give you a great handle on managing your webpage and manipulating JSON data

Comment: Yql returns a specific search parameter result from any page that i want, for example: if i want to get all the names from a name searching service, i use the @id:names parameter to return all the content in it, the problem is that i dont know how to convert the results into text/links. I dont know anything about jquery and i get more confused each time i try to learn it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, depending on which approach you want to take.

First, and simplest, is **server-side generation**.  This is what would result, for example, if a user hits a `Submit` button on a search form to send you his query, your script receives the query and generates the page, then sends that page to the user.  In this case, your question is largely trivial.  In pseudocode:

```
ASSIGN the list of results to list L
FOR EACH ITEM r IN L
    PRINT a string containing an HTML template, substituting the value 
          r where appropriate
```

It's trivial enough that I suspect you want to do this via **DOM manipulation**.  This is what requires JavaScript: you get the query, send the request without refreshing the page, and want to add the results to the DOM.  If you're receiving the list of results, you're already most of the way there.  Using jQuery, you would do the same thing as in the pseudocode above, except that where it has the `PRINT` statement you would have:

```
$(".SearchResults").append("<li>" + r + "</li>");
```

I highly recommend reading through the jQuery tutorial. It's not as hard as you think.

Comment: I see more clearly now, so ill learn it since it seems obvious that the only way i will be able to do something like that will be with JQuery, thanks guys!